# Is it possible to disable stopping a service in Windows?

Tags: service, windows-server

Is it possible to disable stopping a service in Windows?, so the service should be always running and it couldn't be stopped, even if you try to stop it from services list you can't do it, is it possible to do on Windows Server 2012?.

Comment: No. An administrator can always stop a service that is not part of the OS itself. And any service that tries not to be stopped is most likely malware of some sort.

Comment: We encounter at production, a strange behavior for MySQL, it stopped alone and the service is deleted, we've tried to recreate the service and the same problem, we've tried also to lreinstall it and the same problem, we've tried to install another version and again the same problem and if we open the event journal we don't find a useful log, it always says "Normal shutdown"!

Comment: So your solution is to try to find a hack instead of actually solving the problem?

Comment: The problem is we don't know why it got stopped! we've passed many days trying to figure out why it got stopped, but without result!

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a service in Windows:

1. Open CMD with admin privileges (right click on CMD and select “Run as administrator”)
2. Type:

   ```
   SC DELETE <Service name>
   ```

   > ***Note:*** For the `<Service name>`, we have to write the service name, but *not* the display name.
3. Go to the service list and refresh the list (right click and click “Refresh”)